# Django - pass value from html template to python function

Tags: python, django

I am trying to spin first Django project and I am struggling how to pass value to python function from html. Basically, I have 1 placeholder with 3 buttons next to it.
I have file.html in templates.

```
   <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="text" name="name_id" placeholder="placeholder value"/>

        <input type="submit" value="Value 1"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Value 2"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Value 3"/>
    </form>
```

I am trying to pass **placeholder value** to views.py. In views.py I have 3 functions. I want to execute only one of them based on **value**.

Value 1 from file html triggers function 1 in views py
Value 2 from file html triggers function 2 in views py
Value 3 from file html triggers function 3 in views py

I am not sure how to handle urls.py

All files are in same app/folder

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a `name="…"` attribute on the submit `<button>`s:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="text" name="name_id" placeholder="placeholder value"/>

    <input type="submit" name="value1"/>
    <input type="submit" name="value2"/>
    <input type="submit" name="value3"/>
</form>
```

In the view you can then check with:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'value1' in request.POST:
            # …
            pass
        elif 'value2' in request.POST:
            # …
            pass
        elif 'value3' in request.POST:
            # …
            pass
```

Comment: Maybe I dont get it, but I have 3 different functions, not 1. And how do I pass  request from html through urls.py?

Comment: @thankyou: the `some_view` is a "dispatcher". In your case, you thus can for each if condition, call a view function that corresponds with the given name passed by the form.

Comment: I see. Thank you. But I am still confused. How do I call "some_view" from the html and how do I pass "placeholder value" along with the value of the button?

Comment: @thankyou: you define a `path(...)` that points to `some_view`, and you let the form make a request to that path.

Comment: @thankyou: but you use `value="value1"`? Why? Normally it should be `name="value1"`, such that it passes that as POST parameter.

Comment: I have placeholder which value I have to pass and I can access it, but also have to pass second value from value="Value 1 or value="Value 2 or value="Value 3. There are 2 values that I have to pass to views.

Comment: @thankyou: all the other form elements will be passed with the submit button. If you really need two values, then the `some_view` can look at the first value, and add the corresponding second one when calling another view.

Comment: if I print (request.body) in views.py I can see only name_id value from placeholder and csrfmiddlewaretoken. I think I am messing something with the request.
'csrfmiddlewaretoken=thevalueofthetoken&ods_id=thevalueoftheods_id'

Comment: @thankyou: but these are *not* passed in the body, but in the header. So you access these with `request.POST`, you thus query `'value1' in request.POST`.

Comment: If you work with `name="value1"` it will pass it like: `value3=Submit+Query`, so then we can do an *element* check.

Comment: This doesnt work for me:
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'value1' in request.POST:
            function1(request.POST['name_id'])
        elif 'value2' in request.POST:
            function2(request.POST['name_id'])
        elif 'value3' in request.POST:
            function3(request.POST['name_id'])

Comment: @thankyou: but did you use `<input type="submit" name="value1">` so using *name*, not *value*.

Comment: NO, that was the mistake. I have messed up with it, because I thought I didn't explain something properly. If I just change the value to name in html, I got 3 buttons rendered as "submit". So first I had to add in html to each button name=value, keep value=value and continue as you have guided me. Thank you @Willem Van Onsem. Sorry about the frustration. :(